# Create a DataFrame mask based on row/column condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I create a boolean mask where `True` values happen when the index is greater-or-equal than the index where first non-null value occurs at each column? I.e.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1],
        [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1],
        [1, 1, np.nan, 1]
    ],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
)

print(df)

    A    B    C    D
0   NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
1   1.0  NaN. NaN  NaN          
2   NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
3   1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
```

Produces the following boolean mask:

```
array([[False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

In other words, for column A, the first non-null value occurs at index 1, so `"A[1:] = True"`. For column B, `"B[2:] = True"`. And so on.

I've tried to use to native `pd.DataFrame.mask` function:

```
df.mask(df.index >= df.isnull().idxmin(), df)
```

which raises an error due to the misshaping of the conditional array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.ffill()`:

```
print(df.ffill().notna().values)
```

Prints:

```py
[[False False  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]]
```